# What does the _read function for readable streams do in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, stream

I'm reading the docs and there's this description, but I don't understand what it means.

> All Readable stream implementations must provide a _read method to fetch data from the underlying resource.
>
> This method is prefixed with an underscore because it is internal to the class that defines it, and should not be called directly by user programs. However, you are expected to override this method in your own extension classes.
>
> When data is available, put it into the read queue by calling readable.push(chunk). If push returns false, then you should stop reading. When _read is called again, you should start pushing more data.

What is the underlying resource?
When would you actually specify a _read function, meaning what purpose does it serve?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `_read()` function is used to notify the Readable stream that the `highWaterMark` has not been reached and that the stream can feel free to read more data from the underlying resource. The argument passed to `_read()` is a suggestion of the number of bytes (or number of items in the case of `objectMode`) to read from the underlying resource.

The underlying resource mentioned in the documentation is referring to any data source. It could be anything, including another Readable stream or it could be data that you generate dynamically (for example, a Readable stream that provides random binary data).

Comment: Thank you! I would vote the answer up but I don't have the rep to do so. Are there any practical applications for _read that you can think of (other than leaving it blank)?

Comment: It's always practical because by pushing more data when the buffer isn't full you're ensuring that downstream always has data to receive and isn't left waiting for data as much.

Comment: So what would you put inside of the _read function? I know the size is the parameter, but what would the code inside the function look like?

Comment: As previously mentioned it depends on your data source. You have to supply the Readable stream with data from *somewhere*, whether it's from another stream or you generate it yourself (e.g. the random data example). Inside `_read()` is where you'd pull data from that *somewhere* and `push()` it onto your Readable stream.

Comment: ughh, if you call push inside read() you basically get an infinite loop, better to place push calls outside of the read method, right? Also, if anyone could explain the difference between _read() and read() that would be just great. _read is supposed to be internal, so I will never understand why many examples have us overriding it.

Comment: I upvoted the answer because of course it helps, but furthermore, what I don't understand, is I don't know how to properly add data to a readable stream asynchronously. I guess just call readable.push(chunk) from some other part of the code. *But* the major problem with that is we are pushing willy-nilly, and unnecessarily filling up memory. To be precise, we could read an entire file into memory (into the readable stream) before downstream is ready. readable streams *should* have a way to request data when the downstream is ready, which would require a callback, not just plain old this.push()

Comment: That's what the `_read()` callback *is*. It's to signal that more data should be read from the upstream source. If you `push()` and it returns `false`, then stop reading from upstream until the next call to `_read()`. You don't *have to* `push()` from within `_read()`, since `_read()` is merely just a signal.

Comment: @mscdex Thank you for your answer and, in particular, your very last comment which cleared up a lot of confusion for me. After all, the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_push_chunk_encoding) say: *The `readable.push()` method is intended be called only by Readable implementers, and **only from within the `readable._read()` method.*** (emphasis mine) I guess what they really meant is that `push()` should only be called *after* `_read()` has been invoked and only as long as it doesn't return `false`.

Comment: …My problem basically was that, sometimes, I wouldn't have any data to `push()` anymore for a while (as I would be waiting for some user action) and I didn't know how I should tell `push()` about this, short of completely ending the stream via `push(null)`. I thought I had to notify `push()` somehow as the docs say that `_read()` won't be called again until the next `push()`. (Which led to the question of  how would I push out new data once it'd be available without violating the rule that `push()` should only be called from within `_read()`.)